# Caddy reverse_proxy and React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, single-page-application, reverse-proxy, caddyfile

I am unable to setup my `Caddyfile` to work with a React SPA app such that

1. React router routes works
2. Calls to `/api/` (e.g. `/api/foo`) are reverse proxied to another location

With my current `Caddyfile` below, React router appears to be working (visiting `mysite.com/faq` does not give a 404) but calls to the API backend (e.g. `mysite.com/api/foo`) appears to be trying to load a React Router route.

How can we fix this `Caddyfile`?

```
www.example.com {
    redir https://example.com{uri}
}

example.com {
    root * /root/example/frontend/build
    file_server
    encode gzip zstd

    reverse_proxy /api/*  api.example.com:8000

    try_files {path} /index.html
    
    tls admin@example.com

    log {
        output file /root/example/logs/access.log {
                roll_size 100mb
                roll_keep 5
                roll_keep_for 720h
        }
    }
}
```

---

Update: This `Caddyfile` does not work too, React router no longer works, getting an error 404 when visiting `https://example.com/faq`. However, reverse proxy appears to be working: The API server is getting hits when we visit `https://example.com/api/foo`, but its getting them incorrectly as `http://api.example.com:8000/api/foo` instead of `http://api.example.com:8000/foo`

```
www.example.com {
    redir https://example.com{uri}
}

example.com {
    root * /root/example/frontend/build
    file_server
    encode gzip zstd

    reverse_proxy /api/*  api.example.com:8000

    @notAPI {
        not {
            path /api/*
        }
        file {
            try_files {path} {path}/ /index.html?{query}
        }
    }
    rewrite @notAPI {http.matchers.file.relative}
    
    tls admin@example.com

    log {
        output file /root/example/logs/access.log {
                roll_size 100mb
                roll_keep 5
                roll_keep_for 720h
        }
    }
}
```

*Using Caddy v2.4.3*

*Caddy is started using `caddy start --config ~/foo/Caddyfile`*

Answer (score 0):

I got the following to work:

```
http://localhost {
    root * ./trial-ui
    route {
        reverse_proxy /api/* http://127.0.0.1:8080
        try_files {path} /index.html
        file_server
    }
}
```